# I have to write my own trimtoSize() method that creates a new array

Tags: java, arrays

I've been give a prewritten program with the exception of a few methods, one of those being `trimtoSize()`. I know it already exists but for this I have to write my own. I have to make it so it there is empty space within the array I have to create a new array using the same values, and make the size exact. I've been able to compare sizes using `size()` and `data.length` but I'm not sure how to create a new array which is then used since the function doesn't return anything(it's void).

Here's what I have so far.

```
public void trimToSize(){

Array<Integer> temp = new Array<Integer>();

if(size() < data.length){
    int max = size();
    for(int i=0; i<size();i++){
        temp.add(data[i]);
    }
}}
```

As I said before I don't know how to return temp, and it would keep the same max capacity the same as before because its created using a constructor. Is there a way to change the capacity without changing the constructor?

Comment: Please have a quick google for method arguments and return types.  Your answer will be found there.

Comment: You can pass Arraylist in method as parameter once your method call over. You can have its reference no need to return it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't bee sure without seeing the rest of the code, but itappears that this is only part of a class and in that class is an Integer array named data...
If this assumtion is true, then this should work..

```
public void trimToSize() {
    int size = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
        if(this.data[i] != null) {
            size++;
        }
    }
    Interger[] temp = new Interger[size];
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
        if(this.data[i] != null) {
            temp[j] = this.data[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    this.data = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm understanding from your question...  You have a incomplete predefined class that mimics the behaviors of an `ArrayList`.  One behavior you have to define on your own is `trimToSize()`.  According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

[image]

This is just to conserve memory.  So here's a class that I think does just that...

```
public static class MyArrayList {
    private Object[] array;
    private int capacity;
    private int size;
    private int index;

    public MyArrayList(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        array = new Object[capacity];

        index = 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public int add(Object item) {
        if (index == capacity) {
            increaseSize();
        }

        array[index] = item;
        index++;
        size++;

        return index;
    }

    public Object get(int index) {
        if (0 <= index && index < size) {
            return array[index];
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }

    public void trimToSize() {
        if (size < capacity) {
            Object[] newArray = new Object[size];
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, size);
            array = newArray;
            capacity = size;
        }
    }

    private void increaseSize() {
        capacity++;
        Object[] newArray = new Object[capacity];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, array.length);
        array = newArray;
    }
}
```

Here's the usage of this class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyArrayList myArrayList = new MyArrayList(5);
    myArrayList.add(1);
    myArrayList.add(2);
    myArrayList.add(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(myArrayList.get(i));
    }

    myArrayList.trimToSize();
    myArrayList.add(4);
}
```

You'll see that after instantiating `MyArrayList` with a capacity of 5, that there are 5 elements in the array.  Three of which have values 1, 2, and 3 respectively, while the last two are null.

[image]

But after the `trimToSize()` call, the two null items are removed from the array.

[image]

Then when the number 4 is added, the capacity dynamically increases.

[image]

This is definitely not something you would be doing for a job, and seems to be advanced for a basic programming class, but there you have it.  I would only hope that if this is for a class (which I've essentially done your homework for you) that your instructor is good enough to explain this type of behavior to you.  I've been a part-time professor before and have seen many professors that IMO were horrible at explaining theory of programming and applying concepts to code.

### UPDATE

After viewing your profile, I see that you've never accepted anyone's answer which is a complete waste of other's time that try to help you.